# Change file link path structure using regex in PHP

Tags: php, regex

How I can change file link path structure with PHP?
For example I want to do like this:

```
https://old.sitename.com/dir/dir2/dir3/file -name.xxx
```

to

```
https://new.sitename.com/?x=fixparam&f=1111file-name.xxx
```

`fixparam` and `1111` are fixed values. And in file name use `/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_.]/`

Anyone can help me? TNX!

Comment: Where are you doing this replacement?

Comment: @revo its not so important! for example a php function that when I pass old path, return me the new path!

Comment: Add the forward slash to that regex and it should work. You'll need to escape it since you are using it as the delimiter as well. You also need to allow the colon. Maybe something like `[^-\w:\/.]` would do it for you.

Comment: It is important before any one's going to bid a solution. Someone may tag a question with `php` but he actually is asking for Apache mod_rewrite rules or data manipulation within SQL and all these may not fit in one answer. Now, it's cleared.

Comment: @revo I don't think he/she is using Apache (rewrite rule) or SQL, neither use delimiters for their regexs. I'd guess this is being used with `preg_replace`.

Comment: @HoomanMns Your question (despite receiving an answer) is very vague about how your input string may vary.  Are you incorporating any validation logic on these strings in addition to the replacement logic?  `?x=fixparam&f=1111` is fixed, right? is `file` fixed? is `name` fixed? is `https://`  Please show some actual code, with a realistic input string and your exact desired output for your input string -- this gives your question context and helps everyone to understand your issue.  Do you have a collection of strings to process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I can find a solution! A PHP function that can do this!

`$path` variable is old path and this function return the new path that I need:

```
function old_to_new_dlpath($path) {

    $old_name = basename($path);
    $new_name = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\_.]/", '-', $old_name);
    $fix_name = preg_replace('/(_|-)+/', '$1', $new_name);
    $full_url = 'https://new.sitename.com/?x=fixparam&f=1111' . $fix_name;
    return $full_url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below regex:

```
(https:\/\/[\w.]*)([\/\w]*)file ([-\.\w]*)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1aC7Q8/2)

Comment: If it were as simple as this `str_replace('file ', 'file', $string)` could be used. This regex is not a good use of regex.

Comment: @user3783243 there is also a requirement to change path like /dir1/dir2/dir3 to a fix path

Comment: Okay, so need to be a bit more than that `str_replace`. This answer assumes that `file ` is the only invalid filename though. That is probably an example case though. (the domain also apparently changed, this doesn't account for that either)